# Выдает ошибку " Ошибка соединения с MySQL-сервером "

Tags: php, mysql

```
$abc= mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'aliendatabase')
     or die ('Ошибка соединения с MySQL-сервером');
    $query = "INSERT INTO aliens_abduction ( first_name , last_name, ".
"whеп_it_hарреп, hоw_lопg, how_many, alien_description, ".
"what_they_did, fang_spotted, other , emai ) ".
"VALUES ('Салли', 'Джонс', '3 дня назад', '1 день', 'четыре', ".
"'зеленые с шестью щупальцами', 'мы просто разговаривали и играли с собакой', ".
"'да', 'возможно, я видела вашу собаку, свяжитесь со мной' ,'sally@greags-list.net')";
$result = mysqli_query($abc, $query)
        or die ('Ошибка соединения с MySQL-сервером');
mysqli_close($abc);
```

Comment: у тебя 10 полей в INTO и 8-9 полей в VALUES, запятые между значениями не расставлены корректно

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/5Hyc80R.png

Comment: А если выдачу ошибки `die ('Ошибка соединения с MySQL-сервером')` заменить на `die(mysqli_error())` - можно увидеть непосредственное описание проблемы вместо статического текста, не факт, что отражающего действительность (например, если ошибка в запросе - то с соединением-то на самом деле всё в порядке).